# VLAN-tagging based on MAC-Adress

Tags: linux, networking, router, subnet, vlan

we are currently setting up our own router with a Bananpi R64 and ArchLinux as operating system.
We would like to divide our network at layer 2 into different subnets (home, private, guest, ...) using VLANs. The assignment to the subnetworks should be done automatically on the basis of the Mac address of the connected end devices. On the Bananpi we have several physical network interfaces (Wifi and Ethernet).The assignment to the subnets should be as independent from the physical interfaces. This means that regardless of whether a device connects via WLAN or an Ethernet port, it should always end up in the same subnet.
Do you have here ideas whether and how best to implement this? We have already tried to forward the traffic via an ingress chain in nftables to the appropriate subnets by simply changing the destination MAC in the packet. This seems to work halfway, but the ip address assignment with DNSmasq as DHCP server does not work anymore....
If you have any other ideas for splitting traffic other than vlans, we'd appreciate that as well.

Thanks already for your suggestions.

[Division in different VLANs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV7j5.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since VLAN-based L2 filtering is done by Ethernet switches, this feature is also something that needs to be supported by your Ethernet switches.

Most enterprise(-ish) Ethernet switches and Wi-Fi access points support using a RADIUS server to obtain VLANs – as soon as a device connects, the AP contacts the RADIUS server to confirm its access and receives the VLAN ID as part of the "Accept" response. (This is often a part of WPA-Enterprise or 802.1X, but it can also be done with MAC-address authentication.) A common term is "dynamic VLANs".

(There also exist Ethernet switches that support static "MAC VLANs", although often with a very small limit; they're meant to separate things like IP-phones of a specific manufacturer.)

Usually the **router** is not involved in this at all, as it's not where VLAN L2 separation is done in the first place (unless the router is also a switch and/or an AP). Though if you're running hostapd on the BananaPi itself, `dynamic_vlan=` and `macaddr_acl=` would be the relevant settings.